# ng-repeat on transcluded directive not displaying object properties

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, transclusion

I have a couple of menu directives, the outer menu directive has a few menu-item elements inside of it. The bottom three ("Sign Up", "Sign In" and "Profile") work as expected. The links above that are generated by an ng-repeat that loops through an array of objects that are set elsewhere. When I run the code I find that the correct number of menu-items are created but none of the attributes set by the ng-repeat are displaying. The ng-repeat created links have no route, icon or label.

I don't understand. My data looks fine and the transcluded element seems to have access to the menu object, as the appropriate number of menu-items are being output.

Where did my data go?

```
<jrt-menu data-ng-if="menu.shouldRender(authentication.user);">
        <jrt-menu-item 
            ng-repeat="item in menu.items | orderBy: 'position'" 
            label="{{item.title}}" 
            icon="{{item.icon}}" 
            route="{{item.link}}">
        </jrt-menu-item>
        <jrt-menu-item label="Sign Up" 
            route="subitem.link" 
            ng-class="{active: $uiRoute}"
            data-ng-hide="authentication.user">
        </jrt-menu-item>
        <jrt-menu-item label="Sign In" 
            route="/signin" 
            ng-class="{active: $uiRoute}"
            data-ng-hide="authentication.user">
        </jrt-menu-item>

        <jrt-menu-item label="Profile" 
            icon="fa-dashboard" 
            route="/settings/profile" 
            ng-class="{active: $uiRoute}"
            data-ng-show="authentication.user">
        </jrt-menu-item>
    </jrt-menu>
```

The generated HTML:

```
<ul class="jrt-menu" ng-transclude="">
  <!-- ngRepeat: item in menu.items | orderBy: 'position' -->
  <jrt-menu-item ng-repeat="item in menu.items | orderBy: 'position'" label="" icon="" route="" class="ng-scope ng-isolate-scope">
    <li class="jrt-menu__item ng-binding" ng-class="{'vertical': !isVertical(), 'horizontal': !isVertical()}">
      <i class="fa  jrt-menu__icon"></i>
      <!-- ngIf: isActive() && isVertical() -->
    </li>
  </jrt-menu-item>
  <!-- end ngRepeat: item in menu.items | orderBy: 'position' -->
  <jrt-menu-item ng-repeat="item in menu.items | orderBy: 'position'" label="" icon="" route="" class="ng-scope ng-isolate-scope">
    <li class="jrt-menu__item ng-binding" ng-class="{'vertical': !isVertical(), 'horizontal': !isVertical()}">
      <i class="fa  jrt-menu__icon"></i>
      <!-- ngIf: isActive() && isVertical() -->
    </li>
  </jrt-menu-item>
  <!-- end ngRepeat: item in menu.items | orderBy: 'position' -->
  <jrt-menu-item label="Sign Up" icon="subitem.icon" route="subitem.link" ng-class="{active: $uiRoute}" data-ng-hide="authentication.user" class="ng-scope ng-isolate-scope ng-hide">
    <li class="jrt-menu__item ng-binding" ng-class="{'vertical': !isVertical(), 'horizontal': !isVertical()}">
      <i class="fa subitem.icon jrt-menu__icon"></i>Sign Up
      <!-- ngIf: isActive() && isVertical() -->
    </li>
  </jrt-menu-item>
  <jrt-menu-item label="Sign In" icon="subitem.icon" route="/signin" ng-class="{active: $uiRoute}" data-ng-hide="authentication.user" class="ng-scope ng-isolate-scope ng-hide">
    <li class="jrt-menu__item ng-binding" ng-class="{'vertical': !isVertical(), 'horizontal': !isVertical()}">
      <i class="fa subitem.icon jrt-menu__icon"></i>Sign In
      <!-- ngIf: isActive() && isVertical() -->
    </li>
  </jrt-menu-item>
  <jrt-menu-item label="Profile" icon="" route="/settings/profile" ng-class="{active: $uiRoute}" data-ng-show="authentication.user" class="ng-scope ng-isolate-scope">
    <li class="jrt-menu__item ng-binding" ng-class="{'vertical': !isVertical(), 'horizontal': !isVertical()}">
      <i class="fa  jrt-menu__icon"></i>Profile
      <!-- ngIf: isActive() && isVertical() -->
    </li>
  </jrt-menu-item>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you did not post your directive code, it is hard to say but usually when I use ng-repeat in directives, I follow this format in the link: method of the directive.

```
link: function(scope,element,attrs)
{
var el = angular.element(...string of text for my HTML....);
element.append(el);
$compile(el)(scope);
}
```

You need to add the $compile server to your directive of course.  This method works well unless you deeper nested directives in which case I search for 1 of the many recursive services on the net and drop it in to my code.  That way the newly added elements get bound and displayed correctly